# Make div all content below move down if div slides down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make this notification div that slides down if it is active. It slides down using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#notice').slideDown(1000);
         $('.exit').click(function(){
             $("#notice").slideUp(400);
         });
    });
</script>
```

And the style is:

```
#notice {
    background: #E0E0E0;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 30px; 
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    top: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

But how can I make this move everything else down as it slides down, even though the div below is at state 'position: fixed'. And slide everything else back up when it is removed using the .exit link.

Comment: Move everything below as well. If you make a fiddle we can help you more :)

Comment: No @BojanPetkovski. I only want this to happen if the div is on display. If I don't want it active I just remove the whole script and it will be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are one option to do it

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/jvarj4gk/2/

```
$('#notice').slideDown(1000);
 var timer = setInterval(function () {
     $('#fixed').css({
         top: $('#notice').outerHeight()
     });
     if ($('#notice').outerHeight() == $('#fixed').css('top')) {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }

 }, 10);

 $('.exit').click(function () {
     $("#notice").slideUp(400, function(){
         $(this).remove();
     });
     $('#fixed').animate({
         top: 0
     }, 400);

 });
```

**Update**

To move the #body you can do it like this

Example http://jsfiddle.net/jvarj4gk/5/

```
$('#notice').slideDown(1000);
 var timer = setInterval(function () {
     $('#fixed, #body').css({
         top: $('#notice').outerHeight()
     });
     if ($('#notice').outerHeight() == $('#fixed').css('top')) {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }

 }, 10);

 $('.exit').click(function () {
     $("#notice").slideUp(400, function(){
         $(this).remove();
     });
     $('#fixed').animate({
         top: 0
     }, 400);

 });
```

Comment: Thanks! But, What if I wrap a div around all the divs below #notice with fixed div(s) inside. How could I do it then? Because right now it looks like this live: [www.eldeskin.com](http://eldeskin.com)  Password: hallo

It looks like the div that is fixed under is moved a few seconds later....

Comment: Why do you have a margin-top: 100px; on #front? That is causing the blank space.

Comment: Because #header is a fixed div, i need to move the div below down. I removed it and replaced it with padding, but I still have the same problem. Instead of using #fixed I now use #body which is wrapped around all divs below #notice. How do I style so it moves down even with the fixed divs inside? It is now styled as `position: absolute;`

Comment: Thanks! #body works, but #fixed is still moving down slowly seconds after

Comment: Well what do you expect when you have transitions applied to it :D Remove the transitions .withfadeout and it will work as needed. And add padding-top: 40px to #front not 100px :)

Comment: Uh oh. Looks like 
       <div id="account-nav">
          <a href="/account">My Account</a><br>
        {{ 'Log out' | customer_logout_link }} 
       </div> isn't into the #body style. This is another fixed div. As well as #register, #sign, #cart and #forgot-password

Answer (score 1):

You can `animate()` the div below

```
var h = '+=' + $('#notice').height();
$('#fixedDivId').animate({
    top: h;
},1000);
```

And almost the same stuff for slide up but `h='-='+ $('#notice').height();`

**UPD** 
For your code it will look like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $('#notice').height()+'px';
    $('#notice').slideDown({duration:1000, queue:false});
    $('#fixedDivId').animate({
       top: h
    },{duration:1000, queue:false});
    $('.exit').click(function(){
       $("#notice").slideUp(400);
    });
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrx34roa/)

Comment: Thanks, but can't get this to work. How do I put it into my existing script?

Comment: @VemundEldegard Updated my post, take a look on the fiddle.